# I've deleted OSX's partions, how to restore?

Tags: windows-vista, macbook

In a wild attempt to rapidly install vista, i've destroyed a MBP.

I booted the vista setup disk, then deleted the existing OSX partitions - Vista then refused to install *"windows is unable to find a system volume that meets its criteria for installation"*.

So I'm now trying to reinstall OSX and follow a dual boot guide, however now the OSX installer doesn't present any "Destination Volumes" at the "Select Destination" screen early in the installation process.

Am I screwed?

Ashley

Comment: Haha, my friend tried to use Boot Camp and did the same thing, destroyed all the partitions somehow. She reinstalled Mac OS from the CD and has since sworn off windows completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

boot from OSX boot cd (hold c). once on welcome screen, go to utilities, disk utilities, and create a partition. you should be golden from there.

good luck...